# php.ini on goDaddy

Tags: php

I've got a little problem on a goDaddy server. I have a php script (ajaxCRUD) in which there's an upload field, and I can't get it to accept file over the default limit. I always get this (when I output the $_FILE[$fieldname]) :

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "children2.mp3" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=>   string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) }
```

Things I tried :

- Added a parameter in the HTML form ([...]name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"[...])
- Changed the php5.ini at the root of the server, to no avail. After a phpinfo(), no differences are seen, even though the phpinfo clearly indicate it is reading the same php5.ini : [...]/html/php5.ini. Here is what I added in this file :

  upload_tmp_dir = ./temp
  upload_max_filesize = 20M
- Anything under 2M (the default value) is okay, so there's no problem with the upload path or file permission.

I don't have any more idea for the moment, do any of you has one?

Comment: I just signed up for a goddady web hosting and created a database. Is php automatically installed on the server. How can I connect to the database from a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check post_max_size as well. File data is sent as POST data, so post_max_size should always be bigger than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! As always I'm still amazed at how fast people respond here on stackoverflow.com